# PHP equal operator precedence

Tags: php

What's the purpose of checking the value of $_post array from two text input fields like so:

```
$start = $end = ''; // i need to understand this line

if (isset($_POST['start'])) $start = $_POST['start'];
if (isset($_POST['end'])) $end= $_POST['end'];
```

Comment: its `$_POST` not $_post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just sets `$start` and `$end` to `''` in one statement.

Then the following `if`s check to see if something `isset()` before referencing them so that you don't get undefined variable notices.

So the first line is setting the default value in case the `isset()`s fail.

This accomplishes the same (and I prefer):

```
$start = isset($_POST['start']) ? $_POST['start'] : '';
$end   = isset($_POST['end']) ? $_POST['end'] : '';
```

Comment: So it's simple, i just complicated it in my head, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to find out if the variable has been defined. If it hasn't been defined, you are storing undefined variable and you will get an error (notice). That's why the check with `isset()` and storing empty string instead. Also `$_post` should capitalized (`$_POST`).

Answer (score 1):

`$start = $end = '';` sets both variables to `''`: an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that `$start` equals `end` that equals `''`. Therefore `$start` is `''` too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = '';
$end   = '';
```

is same as:

```
$start = $end = ''; // i need to understand this line
```

That assign the value '' to $start and $end. All variable will have the last value of the assignation chain.

the purpose of:
    if (isset($_post['start'])) $start = $_post['start'];

if we look what that does :

```
[pseudo code]
    IF (I HAVE SOMETHING IN $_post['start'])
        THEN
            I CAN ASSIGN THIS VALUE TO $start
```

We do not want to assign an non-existing value to $start.

voila!